# Convert edit_feature into an sp object

Tags: r, r-sp, r-leaflet, geojsonio

Drawing a polygon using R leaflet, how can the drawn object be converted into an `sp` object? The goal is to use it for filtering spatial points.

```
library(leaflet.extras)
library(sp)
library(geojsonio)

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  leafletOutput("mymap",height=800)
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet(
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addDrawToolbar()
    )

  observeEvent(input$mymap_draw_new_feature,{
    feature <- input$mymap_draw_new_feature

    # convert feature into sp object - this fails
    feature_sp <- geojsonio::geojson_sp(feature)

  })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example? There's no need for a shiny shell. If you have a question on converting data, provide needed packages, data and code you've tried to work it out.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure how to do that - setting the leaflet map to a variable is fine, but then how to save the new_feature?  It is easy enough with `mapedit` package, however I'm not using it as it is missing some functionality I need for Shiny.